# Loading finished before of execute all in web

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have  a web page that at moment of do submit, this call to a  image gif that show  using a text of loading using

jQuery showLoading plugin v1.0
The image is showed, but when is load the page where send the action (same page). the web leave of show the image before that finish the load page. The last page have code php that execute a function, the image leave of show , and the funciton no is finished of execute.

I want that the loading follow showing the image until that finish the process

Any idea???

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery.ajax you can set the settings async attribute to false.

```
JQuery.ajax({ ... async: false, ...});
// subsequent code wait 'til ajax call finishes
```

hope it helps
cheers

Comment: I do not make the call with ajax (do a submit to the same page), you could give an example of an ajax call?